# How to show my data on UI Grid using AngularJS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-grid

I have a page where I can do CRUD operations using ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS. I am showing the my Data in the html table. I want to show them with UI Grid as its in http://ui-grid.info/

Can anyone help me show the data in the UI Grid?

This is how my WebApp looks:

**Controller.js**

```
app.controller('crudController', function ($scope, crudService) {

    $scope.IsNewRecordProject = 1;
    loadRecordsProject();

    //Function to load all Projects records
    function loadRecordsProject() {
        var promiseGet = crudService.getProjects(); //The Method Call from service

        promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.Projects = pl.data },
              function (errorPl) {
                  $log.error('failure loading Projects', errorPl);
              });
    }    
});
```

**Module.js**

```
var app;
(function () {
    app = angular.module("crudModule", []);
})();
```

**Service.js**

```
app.service('crudService', function ($http) {

    //Get All Projects
    this.getProjects = function () {
        return $http.get("/api/ProjectsAPI");
    }
});
```

And this is my **Project.cshtml** file

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!-- page content -->
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header-title">
            <h1>Projects</h1>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    @*<div class="right_col" role="main">*@
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ng-controller="crudController">

            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="col-md-4 left-zero">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-5 left-zero">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search by name..." class="form-control" Height="33" Width="200" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
                                    <div style="margin-left: 47px;"><input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" Class="btn btn-primary" /></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 pull-right">

                    <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 0px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select id="cbStatus" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Active</option>
                                    <option>Inactive</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select id="cbPlatform" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Desktop</option>
                                    <option>Web</option>
                                    <option>Mobile</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select id="cbVerify" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Veryfy1</option>
                                    <option>Veryfy2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select id="cbBlank" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Test1</option>
                                    <option>Test2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select id="cbBlank2" class="form-control">
                                    <option>Test1</option>
                                    <option>Test2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td><input id="btnNewProjects" type="button" value="Create New" data-ng-click="ShowInsertPanel = !ShowInsertPanel" class="btn btn-success" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <table class="table table-bordered" align="center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Application</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody ng-repeat="Proj in Projects">
                        <tr ng-click="getProject(Proj)">
                            <td width="50"> <span>{{Proj.id}}</span></td>
                            <td width="150"> <span>{{Proj.name}}</span></td>
                            <td width="150"> <span>{{Proj.application}}</span></td>
                            <td width="150"> <span>{{Proj.status}}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <br />
                <br />

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="ShowInsertPanel">
                        <div class="x_panel">
                            <div class="x_title">
                                <h2>New Project <small></small></h2>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                    <li class="pull-right">
                                        <a class="close-link" data-ng-click="ShowInsertPanel = !ShowInsertPanel"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="x_content">
                                <div class="dashboard-widget-content">


                                    <table class="table table" align="center">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>ID</th>
                                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><input type="text" id="p_id" readonly="readonly" ng-model="id" class="form-control" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><input type="text" id="p_name" required ng-model="name" class="form-control" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Application</th>
                                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><input type="text" id="p_application" required ng-model="application" class="form-control" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                                <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <select id="cbStatus" required ng-model="status" class="form-control">
                                                        <option>Active</option>
                                                        <option>Inactive</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="button" id="new" value="New" ng-click="clearProject()" class="btn btn-default" />
                                                    <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" ng-click="saveProject()" class="btn btn-success" />
                                                    <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteProject()" class="btn btn-danger" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />


    @*</div>*@


</body>
<!-- /page content -->
```

Comment: Please kindly create [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/), and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: Did you check this link http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/106_binding where it shows an example of how to bind data? There is also an example link to plunkr.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]. This question has a lot of code, and no indication of where the grid should be, what columns it needs, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the grid options and return the data as JSON.  Look at the following tutorial documentation: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/106_binding